# Override server's DNS for curl on Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, curl

I'm developing a plugin for WordPress and I need to fetch URL from the same website but as curl job.
My issue is that sometimes websites has CDN that caches HTML, so when I make the curl job, it will fetch data from CDN and not from the website. I cannot use a query string to bypass CDN.
I'm looking for a solution that I would bypass public DNS and use server's IP to resolve for the domain name. Ideally it would be in htaccess.

Comment: in cURL, why don't you use IP Address directly? It would bypass DNS as well as CDN both.

Comment: The usual approach is to use a special, internal domain (or better host name) for this which is _not_ cached by your CDN. Do _not_ use raw IP addresses, that will cause endless trouble later.